# How I can get this output?

Tags: php

I am print the DNS Record of a website using PHP. But the output I am epecting is something different than what I got. Here is the code and output I am getting:

```
    <?php
$domain = "php.net";
$result = dns_get_record($domain,DNS_ANY);
echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode(array('domain'=>$domain,'data'=>$result), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

The output:

```
{
    "domain": "php.net",
    "data": [
        {
            "host": "php.net",
            "class": "IN",
            "ttl": 300,
            "type": "AAAA",
            "ipv6": "2a02:cb41::7"
        },
        {
            "host": "php.net",
            "class": "IN",
            "ttl": 300,
            "type": "TXT",
            "txt": "v=spf1 ip4:72.52.91.12 ip6:2a02:cb41::8 ip4:140.211.15.143 ?all",
            "entries": [
                "v=spf1 ip4:72.52.91.12 ip6:2a02:cb41::8 ip4:140.211.15.143 ?all"
            ]
        },
        {
            "host": "php.net",
            "class": "IN",
            "ttl": 30,
            "type": "MX",
            "pri": 0,
            "target": "php-smtp2.php.net"
        },
        {
            "host": "php.net",
            "class": "IN",
            "ttl": 300,
            "type": "SOA",
            "mname": "ns1.php.net",
            "rname": "admin.easydns.com",
            "serial": 1484930803,
            "refresh": 16384,
            "retry": 2048,
            "expire": 1048576,
            "minimum-ttl": 2560
        },
        {
            "host": "php.net",
            "class": "IN",
            "ttl": 185,
            "type": "A",
            "ip": "72.52.91.14"
        },
        {
            "host": "php.net",
            "class": "IN",
            "ttl": 300,
            "type": "NS",
            "target": "dns3.easydns.org"
        },
        {
            "host": "php.net",
            "class": "IN",
            "ttl": 300,
            "type": "NS",
            "target": "dns2.easydns.net"
        },
        {
            "host": "php.net",
            "class": "IN",
            "ttl": 300,
            "type": "NS",
            "target": "dns1.easydns.com"
        },
        {
            "host": "php.net",
            "class": "IN",
            "ttl": 300,
            "type": "NS",
            "target": "dns4.easydns.info"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am expecting the output to be like this:

```
{
  "domain": "php.net",
  "data": [
    {
      "AAAA": [
        {
          "host": "php.net",
          "class": "IN",
          "ttl": 300,
          "ipv6": "2a02:cb41::7"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "TXT": [
        {
          "host": "php.net",
          "class": "IN",
          "ttl": 300,
          "txt": "v=spf1 ip4:72.52.91.12 ip6:2a02:cb41::8 ip4:140.211.15.143 ?all",
          "entries": [
            "v=spf1 ip4:72.52.91.12 ip6:2a02:cb41::8 ip4:140.211.15.143 ?all"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "MX": [
        {
          "host": "php.net",
          "class": "IN",
          "ttl": 30,
          "pri": 0,
          "target": "php-smtp2.php.net"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "SOA": [
        {
          "host": "php.net",
          "class": "IN",
          "ttl": 300,
          "mname": "ns1.php.net",
          "rname": "admin.easydns.com",
          "serial": 1484930803,
          "refresh": 16384,
          "retry": 2048,
          "expire": 1048576,
          "minimum-ttl": 2560
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "A": [
        {
          "host": "php.net",
          "class": "IN",
          "ttl": 185,
          "ip": "72.52.91.14"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NS": [
        {
          "host": "php.net",
          "class": "IN",
          "ttl": 300,
          "target": "dns3.easydns.org"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NS": [
        {
          "host": "php.net",
          "class": "IN",
          "ttl": 300,
          "target": "dns3.easydns.org"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NS": [
        {
          "host": "php.net",
          "class": "IN",
          "ttl": 300,
          "target": "dns3.easydns.org"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NS": [
        {
          "host": "php.net",
          "class": "IN",
          "ttl": 300,
          "target": "dns3.easydns.org"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Even I would like to know why the `DNS_ANY` work and not DNS_ALL?  Also how I can avoid the duplicate entries in my output, as one can see the the record associated with the `type: NS` is repeated output.
Kindly help me with this question's answer.

Comment: why is `aaaa` in lower case, rest upper case ? :)

Comment: @AlexandrKapustin :P my mistake.. I was trying to show the output I expect and made that lower case ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$domain = "php.net";
$result = dns_get_record($domain,DNS_ANY);
$data = [];
foreach ($result as $item) {
    $type = $item['type'];
    unset($item['type']);
    $data[] = [$type => [$item]];
}

echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode(array('domain'=>$domain,'data'=>$data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```